# Uninstalling the Featured Products modules doesn't remove the field in Catalog

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalog, featured-product

I've been trying several modules that provide "Featured Product" feature on for my store.

I've tried:

- Inchoo
- Daffodil

and a couple of others.  When I uninstall them the field "Featured Product" or similar one in the Catalog doesn't seem to go away.

Is there a way to get rid of this field?

Comment: its probably a template that was left over

Answer (score 1):

Any time you see a field like this showing up in Product Maintenance, it is because it is an attribute. If it is not a system installed attribute, it was created when you installed the module.

Removing the module, unless there is a specific uninstall routine, does not remove attributes once created.

**!!Using a test install on your DEV server!!,** remove the attribute through **Attribute Maintenance** and then test heavily to make sure it is not referenced in any templates or module code. Typical errors for a missing attribute will throw `Call to member function getXXX() on a non-object in xxxxx.phtml` or similar.

If your test system passes with flying colors and doesn't throw any exception errors, congratulations, you should be rid of an unwanted attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to find the upgrade scripts in sql folder of these module and see what all changes they are doing to the database. As these modules are for featured products, my rough guess would be that they must be creating attributes around catalog and nowhere else.

If they are catalog attributes then you can simply delete those from admin panel under catalog -> attribute -> manage attributes.

Hope it helps!